# Flash Won't Load in IE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer

Can someone tell me why this

http://hupcapstudios.com/projects/calendar.html

won't load in IE?

The error message:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. 
  text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: 
  http://hupcapstudios.com/projects/calendar.swf cannot load data from 
  http://www.hupcapstudios.com/projects/getWeather.php?zip=90020.
    at Carousel/loadXML()
    at Carousel()
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using debug versions of flash player while   developing flash/flex. You can get them from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Unless that is your own site/code, this isn't really a programming question. Is it?

Comment: @Marc - that's a good catch. But based on the error message, dlamblin's answer is still correct.

Comment: thanks for the input guys... not sure why I got FIVE down votes for an honest question.  I haven't been getting the security error in my browser.  I'm running a php script to grab the xml and re-output it on my own server to the flash file.  It works in FF for me and was working in IE up untill yesterday.  Again, an honest question.

Comment: 5 (wrongly cast) down votes and 2 (sympathy/compensatory) up votes equals a question with -3 net vote and a bonus of 10 reps.

Comment: still -50 happy to have found this site points.

Comment: 1 more up vote for you, every Flasher in the business has run into this problem, and everyone hates it. A common solution with local to server development is to inject the 'basePath' variable into your swf using swfObject (google 'flashvars') and read it in your main class
`var basePath:String = loaderInfo.parameters.basePath || "localPath";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also doesn't load in Safari 4.

It's got something to do with a 404 on http://www.hupcapstudios.com/crossdomain.xml Likely you didn't follow the rules for cross domain scripting support via a policy file in the flash plugin sandbox. There's probably some information to get you started in [this page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html).

Alternatively you need to make sure that your script is trying to connect back to `http://hupcapstudios.com/` and not `http://www.hupcapstudios.com/` or vice versa, depending on where the `swf` was loaded from.

You can see that as written now it works fine if you load: http://www.hupcapstudios.com/projects/calendar.html so the problem has to do with the cross domain restrictions.

Comment: neither in FF - and I wonder if it'll load in any browser - may be a browser with old flash player that doesn't check crossdomain.xml files while loading.

Comment: Also, see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575771/relative-urls-in-actionscript-3/1576747#1576747

Comment: Thank you for the input, Cay.  Sometimes I have to use absolute paths because I am calling data from my server while testing my file locally.  I figured, since I'm on the same server, perhaps Flash would give me a break on the sandbox vio (which I had no idea was happening in this case, no error message).   The "base" path and keepng in mind that flash doesn't consider where the .swf is but the page it's in as the root of it's location was something I did not know.