# Embed swf XML path issue

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to embed swf to html, and I'm using SwfObject 2.0 My swf has a xml file with it, the swf are in the same folder with index.html, and the xml file is in a subfolder called xml.
So far everything's fine and working. However, I have another html page that's in a subfoler and wants to load the same swf and xml. This time, the xml didn't load. I've checked the path like a million times, and tried this

```
<script>
  var flashvars = {};
  flashvars.folderPath = "../";
</script>
```

nothing works unless I duplicate the xml folder and put it in the subfolder with the html file. Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using direct path in your flash, not relative

I assume the link to your file is looking like `file.xml` which is a relative way
accessing directly - the link to the xml is something like: `/file.xml` or `/path_to/file.xml` (note the slash at the beginning)
this way, wherever you embed your swf, it'll call the xml properly

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, since I did not link the path from the index.html, so am I suppose to do that? is this the right way to do so?
<param name="flashvars" value="xml_path=/xml/data.xml" />

Comment: Yes, this will basically make the flash request for xml work from any location on you website. Whether the swf is at example.com/file.swf or example.com/dir/file.swf the request will always be to example.com/xml/data.xml

Comment: I see, so I still have to state the path in the html page or else it's not going to find it?

Comment: It's up to you whether you specify the path to XML in HTML and pass it as a flash-variable, or you make it fixed (not dynamic) in the flash itself.

Comment: You can also try with the "base" parameter, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575771/relative-urls-in-actionscript-3/1576747#1576747

Answer (score 0):

Unlike CSS, the root path of a Flash movie is the location of the hosting webpage, **not** the location of the SWF file itself. As Michal says, using a full path to the XML file should resolve this issue.